# How many functions defined on $n$ points are possible if each functional value is either $0$ or $1$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, functions

> How many functions defined on $n$ points are possible if each functional value is either $0$ or $1$?

This is from the text *A First Course on Probability* by Sheldon Ross.

The solution he provides is:

Let the points be $1,2,...,n$. Since $f(i)$ must be either $0$ or $1$ for each $i=1,2,...n,$ it follows that there are $2^n$ possible functions.

I don't understand where he gets $2^n$ from...can you elaborate more on this? 
Is there a different way to solve this problem, a longer, more detailed, and clearer way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two choices for $f(1)$, two choices for $f(2)$, and so on. So the number of possible functions is $2\times 2\times \cdots = 2^n$.